# How can I use wordpress for a single purpose / plugin or make it backend-only?

Tags: php, wordpress, backend

yesterday i stumbled across Sergey Burkov's wordpress plugin [3DPrint Lite](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/3dprint-lite/) and I'd like to use it for my website. I'm currently using dokuwiki and don't want to switch to wordpress only for this single purpose. There aren't any similar solutions to Burkov's plugin and coding it all by myself is no option.

.I'm asking myself if its possible to only use wordpress' backend or something similar. So that I would end up with only one page. (Login and so on has to stay available of course)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to switch to wordpress for your whole site, just to use that plugin. Not hard to install wordpress in a directory on your site, and then if you don't want to use any wordpress pages, just use the login from yoursite.com/directory/wp-admin.

If you don't want yoursite.com/directory to show at all then you could do a redirect of that url only, perhaps to your homepage.

Just don't try installing wordpress at yoursite.com since that will mess with your current site.